# Passing a "control" as parameter vs Passing id of the control

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Which way is better ?

1) Passing a control itself as parameter into a function

2) Passing an id ( managed manually)  of the control as a parameter into a function . Say for an array of controls I have `ctrl_Array = [ my_btn, my_mc, my_dtg ]`  and corresponding  `id_Array[0,1,2]`

PS: If my question is difficult to understand, i just wanna know, if it is a good programming practice to pass control references among the classes as function parameters ?

Thanks
Vishwas.

Comment: It will depend on the particular situation. Please explain a little bit more what you are trying to achieve, what does the method do etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say passing a reference is by far the cleanest and easily maintainable solution. In fact I don't think I can come up with a situation in which it would be more preferable to manually maintain a list of references and pass the id's around... Seems like more work and an extra dependency in your client classes.
But maybe I didn't understand the question entirely.

--EDIT--

Just wanted to add that using id's is definitely slower since it involves an extra look-up

--EDIT--

Should've added that I always use interfaces to restrict member access and to allow for polymorphism. To me it goes w/o saying.

Comment: Actually, i personally think, passing the controls makes parts of code vulnerable to lazy coding. Just like having a public attribute inside a class. So when a programmer passes a control as a parameter, it gives full control to other functions to manipulate it's properties. While having an id, would always force programmer to impose restrictions on the access of that control. Additionally, ids help making numerical dependency (1,2,3,4..), that has it's own advantage. I will try to add more explanation in my question, if possible, right now, i am not able to find words.

Comment: Ah, ok, so you wouldn't use the id to look up the control reference in the function it was passed to?
Encapsulation and member access restriction is one of the things interfaces are for. I'd definitely use interfaces. Maybe I should've added that to my answer.